# How to make the page layout stay the same after minimized?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make my page layout stay the same and not become all clumped up when minimized?

[image: this is how the page is supposed to normally look]

but when minimized the page layout becomes

[image: all squished out and the layout is messed up]

. I was wondering how I could fix this? I'm still new to HTML and CSS so I was having trouble with figuring this out.

Sorry if the coding is a bit messed up this is my first time doing html and css! Appreciate all of the help I can get. I'm also doing this with google apps script.

Comment: This is my code on jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9nguoepu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/9nguoepu/7/ I just added some divs wrapping your labels and form inputs and a little css.

```
    <style type="text/css"> * {
    margin: 0
}
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
.header {
    background-color: #8000FF;
    margin:auto;
    width: 50%;
    border:3px solid #41087B;
    padding: 10px;
}
.header img {
    float:left;
    padding: 5px;
}
.header h1 {
    color: white;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align:center
}
.label {
   float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    color: red;
}
.label-container {
width: 50%;
    float:left;
}
.label p {
    padding: 2px
}
.inputBox {
    float:left;
}
.inputBox p {
    padding: 1px
}
.label2 {

    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    color: red
}
.label2 p {
    padding:2px
}
.inputBox2 {
    float:left;
}
.inputBox2 p {
    padding: 1px
}
.contentBackground {
    background-color:#D8D8D8;
    clear:left;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 200px
         display: block;
}
.uploadFile p {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 20px;
    color:red
}
.content p {
    color:red;
    padding: 7px
}
.dropDown p {
    padding: 40px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    height:
}
.moreFiles {
    text-align:center
}
.textBox {
    text-align: center
}
.textBox p {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 5px
}
.button {
    text-align: center
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using hardcoded `px` values (such as `margin-left: 310px`), set `width: 100%` on your body element and use percentage values.  So, instead of `margin-left: 310px` for a `margin-left` of a quarter of the screen, you can use `margin-left: 25%`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: 1000px;`  to your container.  Then the layout should stay consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Setting minimum widths prevents elements from getting squished. https://jsfiddle.net/9nguoepu/9/

HTML

```
<div class="customer-info-container">
            <div class="label">

                <p><b>Customer Name</b>
                </p>
                <p><b>Due Date</b>
                </p>
                <p><b>Phone #</b>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="inputBox">

                <p>
                    <input type="text">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text">
                </p>

            </div>
            <div class="label2">

                <p><b>Contact</b>
                </p>
                <p><b>E-mail</b>
                </p>
                <p><b>PO#</b>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="inputBox2">

                <p>
                    <input type="text">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text">
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
 .customer-info-container{
        width: 800px;
        min-width: 800px;
    }

.customer-info-container{
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .customer-info-container div  {
        display: inline-block;
    }
 .contentBackground {
    background-color:#D8D8D8;
    clear:left;
    min-width:800px;
    width: 60%;

    margin: auto;
    height: 200px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're mixing percentage and pixel units.  Here, I've updated the label/inputs to be all in percentages.
https://jsfiddle.net/9nguoepu/8/

However, note that they still "squish".  If they should remain the same width no matter the users' viewport size, set a `min-width` on your body tag in CSS.  The user will have a horizontal scrollbar in this case, if their viewport is too narrow (like on a mobile device, for example).

I also would recommend making the forms more semantic, as I did in the js fiddle - using `<label>` and keeping them next to/near the input they're labelling.  To be completely accessible, you should add a `for` attribute with the id of the `input`. For example:

```
<label for="customer-phone-num">Phone Number</label>
<input type="text" id="customer-phone-num" />
```

Note that this is an id, so it has to be unique-per-page.

You should also be careful to separate styles from semantics.  For example, the `<b>` tag doesn't mean anything if you're reading the source, but visually, it means it should be bold.  Those kinds of stylistic specifications should be handled in the CSS.  Read this Q&A for more details: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/255366/why-are-the-b-and-i-tags-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you can force everything to stay the same by giving the container a set width. For example, you could define a width to the body:

```
body {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Most modern websites are created with [**Responsive Web Design**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) in mind, meaning that elements on the page will shift around depending on the window size. This allows the same webpage to appear correctly on every device, including small mobile screens.

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is one of the most common frameworks used to create responsive web pages. You might be interested in reading this tutorial:
http://www.revillweb.com/tutorials/bootstrap-tutorial/.